# Passing a token to a Keyword - Robot Framework

Tags: api, token, robotframework

How do I pass a token to another Keyword? 
I've created a session and get the token using the following:

```
${token}  set variable  ${response.json()["authenticationToken"]}
${head}   create dictionary  Authorization=Bearer ${token}  Content-Type=application/json
```

In another Keyword I want to create a new session using the above `${head}`.
How do I pass this correctly?

```
Create session  list    https://whatever.com/    verify=True     headers={head}
```

Because head is a local variable the new session has no clue what this `${head}` is in the above code.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the keyword that gets the token and creates the `${head}` dictionary return it; then you'll have the value in the calling test case / glue keyword, and pass it to the one that's creating the session.

Another possibility is for the keyword getting the token to set the scope of the `${head}` variable to test ([Set Test Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable)) or suite (Set Suite Variable) level - thus it will be defined for all keywords called after that scope setting.